# Compound adjective + adjective + noun

Tags: compound-adjectives

I am having difficulty with this, or maybe my brain has just shutdown. Can you follow a compound adjective with another adjective and then the noun? Or does it always have to be adjective + compound adjective + noun (i.e. the compound adjective **directly** before the noun). I did search the forum and saw a similar discussion regarding adj + adj + noun, but not compound adj + adj + noun, which is why I am asking the question.

Consider the following sentences:

> The band have achieved great success with their self-penned, positive lyrics.

Versus:

> The band have achieved great success with their positive, self-penned lyrics.

Are they both correct (**including the use of commas**)?

I searched the forum and saw a great tip: if the adjectives can be switched around or if you can place an "and" between them (and they still make sense), then you need a comma. However, I don't know if they can be switched around, as I'm uncertain as to whether it makes sense with "self-penned" before "positive lyrics".

The reason I got confused was because I read something in a dictionary that said the word "feel-good" has to be placed directly before a noun e.g. "positive feel-good music" and not "feel-good, positive music". Wondered if this applies to compound adjectives like "self-penned".

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not consider using "and" in place of comma? Does the order make any difference?

Comment: Hi, "and" would work, but still wanted to know if it was correct in either order and with the commas.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with the dictionary. I think "feel-good, positive music" would work if that were your target sentence.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, you treat a compound adjective the same as a normal adjective; So, yes, both of your sentences would be correct, commas and all.

My opinion, though, is that the second sentence sounds less awkward than the first.

Comment: Ok thanks! You're right it does sound less awkward, so I opted to use it, although I did omit the commas.

Comment: Your comment 'you treat a compound adjective the same as a normal adjective' seems to imply that the question is not too complex. But there is a 'royal order of adjectives'. Or rather, different versions. And even the best seems to have exceptions.